# Which MVC framework in Perl has its own standalone server?

Tags: django, perl, model-view-controller, testing, frameworks

I am creating an automated testing framework in Perl for regression tests. I would like to post my results from the test machines. I have used django before where the server ran standalone with no installation needed. Which MVC framework in Perl has its own standalone server? Basically, which of the Perl MVC frameworks is closest to  django's server capability and DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principles?

P.S. I will not rewrite my framework in python

P.S.S I will not use Perl framework and django as MVC

(no python on servers :( )

Comment: How ancient are these servers?  Python's pre-installed on almost everything.

Comment: You are telling me! I have to go through the longest bueracraptic process to get anything installed on the testing servers. Not worth the effort for the amount of testing I am doing

Comment: you say 'no python on servers' like its a bad thing.

Comment: Make sure you're not re-inventing the wheel. See if Smolder (http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Smolder) already does what you need.

Comment: @james2vegas its not a bad thing I am just saying getting it installed is a horrible painful process

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Catalyst comes with a built-in test server - check [Catalyst::Manual::Tutorial](http://search.cpan.org/~hkclark/Catalyst-Manual-5.8000/lib/Catalyst/Manual/Tutorial.pod) for more details. [This](http://search.cpan.org/~hkclark/Catalyst-Manual-5.8000/lib/Catalyst/Manual/Tutorial/03_MoreCatalystBasics.pod#Test_Run_The_Application) looks like a good place to start.

Comment: In the Catalyst Manual, there is an interesting section about the pros/cons of each deployment solutions in Catalyst: http://search.cpan.org/~hkclark/Catalyst-Manual-5.8000/lib/Catalyst/Manual/Cookbook.pod#Deployment

Answer (score 7):

Every popular Perl web framework comes with it's own server: Catalyst, CGI::Application, Jifty. Most popular and DRY-following is Catalyst (don't know about DRY in Jifty).

Also there test result aggregators like Smolder.

Answer (score 6):

[Catalyst](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Catalyst) comes with it's own server `script/myapp_server.pl`.  You can also deploy with our without a reverse proxy using the built in server, but in this case it's advisable to use [Catalyst::Engine::HTTP::Prefork](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Catalyst::Engine::HTTP::Prefork): `CATALYST_ENGINE='HTTP::Prefork' script/myapp_server.pl`

I believe [Jifty](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Jifty) also has a built in dev server, as does [Squatting](http://search.cpan.org/perodoc?Squatting), but I haven't used either of them.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/).
I don't know if it has a stand alone server, but it's Perl with MVC,

Comment: It can be made to use HTTP::Server::Simple, so you could probably grow a "stand alone server" off that...